# Windows 10 DNS error with a heavy load

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

It seems when my computer gets too many open connections the DNS seems to start returning an invalid IP addresses. As soon as this happens every first ping to anything returns my router 10.1.10.1 but everything after it works. Other computer on the network have no issues. The bandwidth is not fully saturated. Its just a lot of open and pending connections. I have tried comcast DNS, opendDNS and Googles open DNS. All do the same thing under load. I have read about some issues with the Windows 10 DNS client. However for some reason I can't stop the Windows 10 DNS client service. In fact I cant do anything to the DNS client service. I get zero options even as an admin. As soon as the issue happens. It will stay this way till I back down the number of outgoing connections. I ran a VM on the machine at the same time as the issue. The VM works correctly while the host Windows 10 shows the DNS issue.

I did enable "**Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution**" in Group Policy Editor.

I did not seem related but I also added "**DisableSmartNameResolution**" to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient**

Windows 10 is fully updated, latest drivers for everything. I'm completely stumped. I have never seen anything like it before. Example ping below.

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.213.110] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.1.10.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 216.58.213.110: bytes=32 time=188ms TTL=46
Reply from 216.58.213.110: bytes=32 time=179ms TTL=46
Reply from 216.58.213.110: bytes=32 time=199ms TTL=46
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a DNS problem?  Based on the ping output, DNS is working fine.

Comment: Everything seems to work correctly otherwise. A VM that's on the same machine will work correctly even when the host does not. I forgot to add routing tables but there is nothing abnormal there. DNS cache its self looks fine. I would disagree DNS is working fine. It is returning addresses. But its not returning the correct address.

Comment: You misunderstand how DNS works. When you issue the ping command, a DNS query converts the hostname  google.com into the IP address  216.58.213.110. As evidenced by the first line of your output `Pinging google.com [216.58.213.110]`, this is happening correctly. After that, DNS is out of the picture.

Comment: Any idea what to look at next then? Or why my first hope to the router would not work by every hope after does?

Comment: Start by re-writing the question to concisely state the problem without the part about DNS being the cause. For some help with this, check out the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Then ping me and I'll be glad to take another look.